# How to generate a custom URL from a html input?

Tags: javascript, html, url, search, search-engine

I want to create a search bar which takes in a query and adds the rest of the URL then goes to the site. For example

Input:   **walmart**
Output:  http://www.example.com/?t=w&p=0&q=**walmart**

then the program navigates to the link that is generated. This is like how Google Chrome's omnibox works.

Comment: OK. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

just simple html form

```
<form method="GET" action="http://www.example.com/">
   <input type="text" name="q">
   <input type="hidden"  name="t" value="w">
   <input type="hidden"  name="p" value="0">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's something I made for my site:

trapper.site90.net/luckysearch

You may use my code if you want. I tested it. Just use inspect element on my page. :D